# Python Sqlite3 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
def get_coffee_name(coffee_type):
    if coffee_type == "Hot":
        conn = sqlite3.connect('coffee.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        coffee_id = rand_coffee()
        c.execute("SELECT tag FROM coffees WHERE id = '%s'" % (coffee_id))
        while True:
            coffee_type = c.fetchone()[0]
            print(coffee_type)
            if coffee_type == "Hot":
                conn.close()
                conn = sqlite3.connect('coffee.db')
                c = conn.cursor()
                c.execute("SELECT name FROM coffees WHERE id = '%s'" % (coffee_id))
                return c.fetchone()[0]
                break
```

Returns

```py
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried other solutions for loop but it didn't worked that way too.

`coffee_type` is Cold or Hot and not none at all times.

Comment: c.fetchone() doesn't return anything, but you try to get its first element with [0[. This is equivalent to None[0], and hence the error you're seeing.

Comment: @Roy2012 `c.fetchone()` actually returns `('Hot',)`

Comment: Nit: Remove all code after a “return” to avoid false beliefs. The “break” in this code can never be reached: or maybe the indenting is incorrect? *shrug*

Comment: @user2864740 Intending is correct and I edited break part but still the same error

Comment: Can you check just printing the row, for row in cursor:
  print(row)......just in case if any rows exists.

Comment: Yes, it is not null @PavanChandaka

Comment: `coffee_type` is not the problem.  The only subscripting you are doing is on the return value of the `.fetchone()` call.  You should print out the result `c` after executing the SQL on the database to see what it returned.

Answer (score 0):

the cursor.fetchone() sqlite call returns a tuple such as (1,) for example, and you can't refer to it nicely with an index or subscript like you can with a list, so do this sort of thing:

1. where x = (1,) -- this is the tuple that c.fetchone() returns
2. First, cast tuple as a list
3. Then, access the subscriptable list object "y" as you wish

```
x = (1,)
y = list(x) 
print(y[0]) 
1
```